# get items from a list filter from another list

Tags: c#

I need to get the item from a list but filter the id from another list of id. Here is a my code, I can't figure out the problem. Any help please?

```
var lstStatus = new List<int> {(int) SurveyRequestConstants.EnumSurveyRequestStatus.Open,
            (int) SurveyRequestConstants.EnumSurveyRequestStatus.InProgress,
            (int) SurveyRequestConstants.EnumSurveyRequestStatus.OnHold};   
var surveyRequestList = SurveyRequestRepository.Queryable().AsEnumerable().ToList();
var surveyRequests = (from first in surveyRequestList
                      join second in lstStatus
                      on first.SurveyRequestStatus.Id equals second
                      select new ListItem(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",  
                                                        first.Id.ToString(),
                                                        first.Tenant.TenantLabel, 
                                                        first.CreatedDate), 
                                                        first.Id.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Tip: Don't post code which will not run when one tries to run it! We don't have SurveyRequestConstants, SurveyRequestRepository ...

Comment: I am expecting a values from surveyRequestList list that contains lstStatus list. lstStatus list in a collection of status id's uses to filter the results in surveyRequestList

Comment: @sprinter252- Sorry I can't put all the codes here because it is very long, I just highlighted the problem. I know there's a lot of expert here who can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to filter the surveyRequestList based on items in lstStatus

```
var surveyRequests = surveyRequestList
.Where(x => lstStatus
.Any(y => y == x.Id))
.Select(x => new ListItem(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",  
                                         first.Id.ToString(),
                                         first.Tenant.TenantLabel, 
                                         first.CreatedDate), 
                                         first.Id.ToString()));
```

Hope this is what you are looking for?